# JavaScript recursive operation array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this (arr), how do I want to get an array like (arr2)? Where the 'start' and 'end' elements are fixed values。

**Original array：**

```js
var arr = [
  {form: 'start', to: 'task-1'},
  {form: 'start', to: 'task-4'},
  {form: 'task-1', to: 'task-2'},
  {form: 'task-2', to: 'end'},
  {form: 'task-1', to: 'task-3'}
]
console.log(arr)
```

**Expected array：**

```js
var arr2 = [
  {form: 'start', to: 'task-1'},
  {form: 'task-1', to: 'task-2'},
  {form: 'task-2', to: 'end'},
]
console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: Basically, you have a graph here. So use one of the more common graph representations and run a (breadth|depth)-first-search on it.

Comment: may be your expected array list seems like group by 'form' and first record 'to', Am i correct.?

Comment: @chandukomati Yes, the first is form: start and the last is to: end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursively find object and push to result array. Here is sample code.

```js
var arr = [
  {form: 'start', to: 'task-1'},
  {form: 'start', to: 'task-4'},
  {form: 'task-1', to: 'task-2'},
  {form: 'task-2', to: 'end'},
  {form: 'task-1', to: 'task-3'}
]


const getTo = search => arr.find(x => x.form === search).to;

let form = 'start';
let to = '';
const res = [];

while (to !== 'end') {
  to = getTo(form);
  res.push({form, to});
  form = to;
}

console.log(res)
```

Comment: This seems to assume, that there is only one element per `form` entry. How does your algorithm cope with the duplicates like the two `from: 'task-1'` elements?

Comment: @Sirko, Yes, my assumption is that finds the first element in duplicates. Based on the output mentioned in question and summary, "recursive " approach to get the path, this will be sample solution. Agree that this will not address duplicates. There can be lot of variations to it, `getting all possible paths`, or  `get short path (less nodes)` or `long path` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is it.

```js
var arr = [
  {form: 'start', to: 'task-1'},
  {form: 'start', to: 'task-4'},
  {form: 'task-1', to: 'task-2'},
  {form: 'task-2', to: 'end'},
  {form: 'task-1', to: 'task-3'}
]
// console.log(arr);

const obj = arr.reduce((accum, value) => {
    const formId = value.form; 
    const to = value.to; 
    if (!accum[formId]) {
        accum[formId] = to;
    }
    return accum;
}, {});

const arr2 = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {
    return {
        form: key, 
        to: value
    }
});
console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: There are duplicates  for  `from` in the input. Doesn't you lookup ignore those? So if the order of entries in the input changed, you algorithm would not work anymore, I guess.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, I misunderstand the question. :( Thanks